# Import an image using Matex without the path of the image inserted in the output

Tags: matex

I am playing with [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) to include an image. It works but it also displays the path of the image in the output which messes things out.

Here is a MWE (on windows with 11.3)

```
<< MaTeX`
SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{graphicx}"}];
MaTeX["This is a test \\includegraphics[width=.5\\textwidth]{C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/11.3/Documentation/English/System/ExampleData/pearls.png} with data"]
```

which gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'd like the path of the images not to show in the text output.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there a way to do that?

MaTeX Version 1.7.4, Mathematica 11.3 on windows 10.

Could someone on windows 10 please try to see if they can reproduce this?

**Updated**

I also tried using `\text{}`

```
<<MaTeX`
MaTeX["\\text{Test \\includegraphics[width=.5\\textwidth]{C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/11.3/Documentation/English/System/ExampleData/pearls.png} image}","Preamble"->{"\\usepackage{graphicx}"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I just tried this on macOS with MacTeX 2018 and I cannot reproduce the problem. I see only the images, not the path.  I don't know why the path appears for you. http://i.stack.imgur.com/U8Bw2.png

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for trying. It might be a Platform related then? There are no errors or warning generated also.

Comment: Can you try putting it in `\text{}`?  Does it work then?

Comment: @Szabolcs I did. I tried exactly your example. It did not work. I will now post that as well.

Comment: I suggest you create a TeX-only minimal example and ask on TeX.SE.  Do let me know if you found out why it happens or if you have a solution!  To create a minimal example, do `ClearMaTeXCache[]` before the `MaTeX` call and add the option `"TeXFileFunction" -> Print`. This will show you the TeX source that MaTeX generates. As a first simplification, replace the `\MaTeX{ ... }` with simply `$ ... $`.  Then you can remove most of the preamble (which just serves to define `\MaTeX`).

Comment: It's almost certainly this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29438/6302

Comment: Yep, I was able to reproduce with a path containing spaces, and also fix it with `\usepackage{grffile}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the file path that you provided contains spaces. Everything after the first space is interpreted as text.  This is discussed in this TeX.SE thread:

- [Prevent the file path of an image appearing above the image when using \begin{figure} \includegraphics{filepath}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29438/6302)

As mentioned there, the solution is to use [grffile](http://ctan.org/pkg/grffile) package.

Thus, use

```
"Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{graphicx}", "\\usepackage{grffile}"}
```